# pwnhammer not dropping from the wall of flesh

Tags: terraria-mobile

The pwnhammer isnt dropping from the wall of flesh in terraria mobile.  **im playing the 1.3 version, not the 1.2, so please don't put this as duplicate from those other ones from years ago.**
ive fought him 3 times, and i never got the pwnhammer. i looked everywhere *even in the lava* and never got one.
why?

Answer (score 0):

The WoF does not drop the drops directly. There should be a box that is themed around your world’s evil (corruption/crimson) with all the drops inside. This is do you can easily find the drops.
From the wiki:

> When the Wall of Flesh is killed, it leaves its drops in a floating, fully-enclosed frame of Demonite Brick for Corruption worlds, Desktop Version Console Version Mobile Version or Crimtane Brick for Crimson worlds.

Comment: yes i know that, as i fought him on pc, but the pwnhammer was not there.

Comment: That really wierd

Comment: i know right!!!